# AngularJS input type="radio" and ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

I have inherited a solution developed in AngularJS (1.5), bootstrap and perhaps something else. I really don't understand too much of this type of development. But I am faced with a problem to solve.
The site displays news in one of two ways:

list:
[image: List mode]

or grid:
[image: Grid mode]

The default mode is list. The user can change the mode through options located at the top:
[image: options]

The user can see the detail of a news item by clicking on the title, but when returning the news is always presented in *list* mode, regardless of what mode it was in. *What is requested is that the mode selected by the user be maintained*.

The options are in a div and a label:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="view-card-mode" data-intro="{{uikey.chTipoVista}}" data-position="bottom">
    <label class="btn btn-default grid-view" title="{{uikey.VistaGrilla}}">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="grid-view" autocomplete="off" checked><i class="fa fa-th"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default list-view active" title="{{uikey.VistaLista}}">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="list-view" autocomplete="off"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

But in the controller of this page there is no reference to these controls, in fact I don't know why they work, since indeed the view changes shape.

I've tried adding `ng-click` and `ng-change` to `inputs`, `labels` and `i`, but they don't respond. For example if I add in view:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="grid-view" autocomplete="off" ng-click="saveViewMode()" checked> <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.saveViewMode = function () {
    console.log("finally");
};
```

nothing happens.

What I'm trying to do is keep the view mode in a variable in the $scope to retrieve it on return.

Beyond asking for help on how this would be solved, there is something that drives me crazy: ***how is this working?***

I need to clarify that the site works normally, there are no problems. I just have to add this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have replicated your problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/v6hpadko/ please check and test are you able to make it work in your app?

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you very much for your response.
Fortunately, I was able to return to my work.

The problem, precisely, is that this does not work in this project. The "option buttons" change, the view is updated, there is no related event on the "controller" side.

What I have noticed is that the way this is done is different from what I have seen in angularjs, even with my lack of experience.

I'm going to update the question to be able to add some more image.

Again thank you very much.